# Sobolev spaces on Cartesian products

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We have a canonical isomorphism
$$ C^0(X,C^0(X,Y)) \simeq C^0(X \times Y, Z)$$ 
given by $f \mapsto \hat{f}$, where $\hat{f}(x,y) = (f(x))(y)$.

Is there a similar statement for Sobolev space?
For example is it true that
$$H^1(X, H^1(Y,Z) ) \simeq H^1(X \times Y, Z)$$

(notations : $H^1 = W^{1,2} = L^2_1$)

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't true: in the space on the left-hand side, you have mixed derivatives of second order (e.g. w.r.t. $X$ and $Y$). You would rather have
$$
H^1(X,L^2(Y,Z)) \cap L^2(X, H^1(Y,Z)) = H^1(X \times Y, Z).
$$
If I do not miss something, this should just follow from the definitions.